# Revert-buffer ---> Discard unsaved changes without y/n prompt

Tags: buffers, revert-buffer

```
(setq revert-without-query '(".*"))
```

With this extra line in .emacs file, i have configured emacs to revert buffers without any prompt. It doesn't prompt for clean buffers but when the buffer has `unsaved` changes, it `prompts` for confirmation.

So, how to use `revert-buffer` with absolutely no prompts (no matter if buffer is clean (or) dirty)?

Comment: *What's your question?* With no question posed, it risks being closed...

Comment: changed!!!!!!!!

Comment: OK. The answer is `(revert-buffer t t)`.

Comment: `(setq revert-without-query '(".*"))` manual says, this line must turn off the prompts, but it didn't? are we giving wrong params to the variable?

Comment: `revert-without-query` determines which buffers will be reverted without querying, It does not turn off querying. More precisely, it *reverts the file without querying if the file has changed on disk and you have not edited the buffer.* If you have edited the buffer then it has no effect.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not sure what you're asking. But FWIW, I use this, and I bind it to `<f5>`:

```el
(defun revert-buffer-no-confirm ()
  "Revert buffer without confirmation."
  (interactive) (revert-buffer t t))
```

Note that you probably do **not** want to redefine or advise `revert-buffer`. You probably want to change the behavior only for interactive calls (there are plenty of Lisp calls to `revert-buffer`, and you don't want to affect their behavior).

That's why I define a separate command, which I use when I want to revert without being prompted.